# Location of network settings class in android jellybean

Tags: android-source, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I’m developing for android jelly bean and I would like to add a field to the network settings menu, but can’t seem to find it in the android source code….
I’ve looked in packages-apps-settings-src-android-settings but then didn’t know exactly where to look.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first have a look at the `packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/setting_headers.xml` file which list the different categories used in the Settings app.

Then, you can implement a new category by looking how others are implemented - for example the "Data usage" setting is implemented in `src/com/android/settings/DataUsageSummary.java` (the fragment is referenced from the `setting_headers.xml` file).